# trying to take diff between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as below:

```
name   country    Join Date      End date 
Wrt     IND        1-2-2016      8-9-2017
Grt     China      3-2-2015     12-6-2018
frt     France     8-3-2017     continuing 
srt     Scottland   9-4-2018     continuing
crt     china       9-7-2016     7-8-2018
```

I am trying to find the difference between Join Date and End date. I tried to use `f9['Num of days'] = f9['End date '] - f9['Join Date']`, but received the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'float'
```

My expected output should be:

```
   name   country    Join Date      End date   diff 
   Wrt     IND        1-2-2016      8-9-2017   395
   Grt     China      3-2-2017      12-6-2018  160
   frt     France     8-3-2017     continuing  continuing
   srt     Scottland   9-4-2018     continuing  continuing
   crt     china       9-7-2017     7-8-2018     280
```

Comment: [This](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/difference-two-dates-days-weeks-months-years-pandas-python-2/) may help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert both columns to datetimes with parameter `errors='coerce'` for missing values if wrong dates like strings `continuing` and if necessary add also parameter `dayfirst=True`, then subtract values, get days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) from timedeltas and last if necessary replace mising values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
f9['Join Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['Join Date'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
f9['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['End date'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)

f9['Num of days'] = (f9['End date'] - f9['Join Date']).dt.days.fillna('continuing')
print (f9)
  name    country  Join Date   End date Num of days
0  Wrt        IND 2016-02-01 2017-09-08         585
1  Grt      China 2015-02-03 2018-06-12        1225
2  frt     France 2017-03-08        NaT  continuing
3  srt  Scottland 2018-04-09        NaT  continuing
4  crt      china 2016-07-09 2018-08-07         759
```

Or:

```
f9['Join Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['Join Date'], errors='coerce')
f9['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['End date'], errors='coerce')

f9['Num of days'] = (f9['End date'] - f9['Join Date']).dt.days.fillna('continuing')
print (f9)
  name    country  Join Date   End date Num of days
0  Wrt        IND 2016-01-02 2017-08-09         585
1  Grt      China 2015-03-02 2018-12-06        1375
2  frt     France 2017-08-03        NaT  continuing
3  srt  Scottland 2018-09-04        NaT  continuing
4  crt      china 2016-09-07 2018-07-08         669
```

Also last step should be replace missing values, but lost `datetime`s column, get mixed strings with `datetimes`, so later datetimelike functions failed:

```
f9['End date'] = f9['End date'].fillna('continuing')
print (f9)
  name    country  Join Date             End date Num of days
0  Wrt        IND 2016-01-02  2017-08-09 00:00:00         585
1  Grt      China 2015-03-02  2018-12-06 00:00:00        1375
2  frt     France 2017-08-03           continuing  continuing
3  srt  Scottland 2018-09-04           continuing  continuing
4  crt      china 2016-09-07  2018-07-08 00:00:00         669
```

EDIT:

You can add multiple condition, from top number or bottom numbers, also here is possible use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) function:

```
f9['Join Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['Join Date'], errors='coerce')
f9['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['End date'], errors='coerce')

f9['Num of days'] = (f9['End date'] - f9['Join Date']).dt.days

m1 = f9['Num of days'] > 730
m2 = f9['Num of days'].between(365, 730)
m3 = f9['Num of days'] < 365 
m4 = f9['Num of days'].isna()

f9['Status'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3,m4], ['U','L', 'N','EOL']) 

f9[['End date','Num of days']] = f9[['End date','Num of days']].fillna('continuing')
print (f9)

  name    country  Join Date             End date Num of days Status
0  Wrt        IND 2016-01-02  2017-08-09 00:00:00         585      L
1  Grt      China 2015-03-02  2018-12-06 00:00:00        1375      U
2  frt     France 2017-08-03           continuing  continuing    EOL
3  srt  Scottland 2018-09-04           continuing  continuing    EOL
4  crt      china 2016-09-07  2018-07-08 00:00:00         669      L
```

Another idea is use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for binning:

```
f9['Join Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['Join Date'], errors='coerce')
f9['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(f9['End date'], errors='coerce')

f9['Num of days'] = (f9['End date'] - f9['Join Date']).dt.days

f9['Status']=pd.cut(f9['Num of days'],bins=[-np.inf, 365, 730, np.inf],labels=['U','L', 'N'])
f9['Status'] = f9['Status'].cat.add_categories(['EOL']).fillna('EOL')
f9[['End date','Num of days']] = f9[['End date','Num of days']].fillna('continuing')
print (f9)
  name    country  Join Date             End date Num of days Status
0  Wrt        IND 2016-01-02  2017-08-09 00:00:00         585      L
1  Grt      China 2015-03-02  2018-12-06 00:00:00        1375      N
2  frt     France 2017-08-03           continuing  continuing    EOL
3  srt  Scottland 2018-09-04           continuing  continuing    EOL
4  crt      china 2016-09-07  2018-07-08 00:00:00         669      L
```

Comment: @jezael end date should contains continuing

Comment: Thanks @jezael  I want make other new column  where >365 days should print S , >365<730 should SS, and continuing should be continuing i used below code m1 = 
m2 = f9['Num of days'] > 365
m3 = f9['Num of days']  >365&<730
m4 = f9['CSDate'] ="EOL"
f9['Status'] = np.select([ m2, m3,m4], ['S',SS','EOL'])

Comment: can you please help me on this

Comment: @ShravyaVaggu - Added 2 solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

First convert both columns in date using to_datetime
then subtract and get days using .dt.date

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['wrt','grt','frt'],
                   'country':['ind','china','france'],
                   'join_date':['1-2-2016','3-2-2015','8-3-2017'],
                   'end_date':['8-9-2017','12-6-2018','continuing']})

df['join_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['join_date'],errors='coerce').dt.date
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'],errors='coerce').dt.date

df['diff'] = (df['end_date'] - df['join_date']).dt.days
df = df[['join_date','end_date','diff']].fillna('continuing')
print(df)
```

Comment: the `fillna` command will replace all cells in the dataframe, not just the ones in the diff column. I think that might be overly broad for OPs use case.  Otherwise good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do is convert the "Join Date" and "End date" series to the numpy array and for that the dtype = np.datetime64 and than take a difference and you will get the difference array store it into your dataframe. 
Also fill the "continuing" cells with the current datatime of any date you want to fill.(Depending on your case)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that can be run in a jupyter notebook.

```
# imports necessary
import datetime as dt 

# raw data to make dataframe
raw_data = {
    'name': ['Wrt', 'Grt', 'frt', 'srt', 'crt'],
    'country': ['Ind', 'China', 'France', 'Scottland', 'china'],
    'Join Date': ['1-2-2016', '3-2-2015', '8-3-2017', '9-4-2018', '9-7-2016'],
    'End date': ['8-9-2017', '12-6-2018', 'continuing', 'continuing', '7-8-2018']
}

pdf = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

# convert the dates into timestamps
pdf['join_date'] = pdf['Join Date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y'))
pdf['end_date'] = pdf['End date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y') if x is not 'continuing' else None)

# calculate diff
pdf['diff'] = pdf.apply(lambda x: str(x['end_date'] - x['join_date']).split(' ')[0] if x['end_date'] is not pd.NaT else 'continuing', axis=1)

# display result
pdf.head()
```